# Using Google Fonts within Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, google-font-api

I'm having a not very fun time trying to use Google Fonts Api within a Facebook App.

*It works* on my application **outside** Facebook but when I'm **inside the Facebook App** the fonts *do not work*.

I'm including the font this way:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

I will love to provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to change

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

to

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Facebook block external http resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just leave out the protocol-portion of the link:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the http protocol. Facebook apps would not load any resources that are not secure - ie not linked via https. I've had the same problem and changing the protocol prefix to 'https' worked.